# Where to place Laravel Listener logic

Tags: php, laravel

I would like to associate an Order (ID saved in user session) when a user signs up.

I have created a event and a listener as documented in Laravel site. The problem I'm having is that I'm not sure where the logic to associate the records should go, I initially put this in the `Order Controller` but the app would try to reference Builder::attachOrderToUser instead.

I moved the method into my Model and it worked however now I'm given the error:

> Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::attach()

Could someone point out where this logic should actually go?

Method in Order Model:

```
/**
 * Attach Order to Customer
 *
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public static function attachOrderToUser($order_id, $user_id)
{
    // @TODO: Wrap around event handler
    $user = User::find($user_id);

    if($user->order()->attach($order_id))
        return true;
    else
        return false;

}
```

Here is my listener code:

```
namespace App\Listeners;

use App\Events\UserQuickSignUpComplete;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;

use Auth;
use Session;
use App\Order;
use Illuminate\Http\Request; 

class AttachGuestOrderToUser
{
    /**
     * Create the event listener.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Handle the event.
     *
     * @param  UserQuickSignUpComplete  $event
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle(UserQuickSignUpComplete $event)
    {
        // get currently logged in user (was signed in on method that triggers event)
        $user = Auth::user();
        // get order
        $order = Session::get('last_transaction.order_id');
        // attach order to user
        Order::attachOrderToUser($order['order_id'], $user['id']);
    }
}
```

Any other suggestions would also be appreciated!

Comment: Why the indirection? In `handle`, you can `Auth::user()->order()->attach(Session::get('last_transaction.order_id'))` and have an integration test confirm the behavior.

Comment: Try `$user->order` instead of `$user->order()`

Comment: @bishop should logic go straight into the handle? I thought it was best practise to keep this in the Controller or a Repository?

Comment: Best practice is to separate concerns and do one thing in each unit of code. Sometimes to follow that practice means to put code into a controller. Sometimes into a repository. Sometimes into a service (and note that an event handler is a specialized service). In my mind, this code *is a service* so the logic can legitimately go into the event handler.

Comment: @bishop thanks for your response, please create an answer for me to mark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Attaching two objects together reads as a *service* to me. Where should such a service go, then, is the question. A controller doesn't feel right, because we're not controlling user actions. A repository doesn't feel right, because we're dealing with two separate model instances (rather than a collection of the same kind of models).

But look at the name of your event listener: `\App\Listeners\AttachGuestOrderToUser`. That's a very specific name that suggests a specific job. In my mind, that class *is already a service*. So I'd simply put the logic you need right in that listener.

```
namespace App\Listeners;

use App\Events\UserQuickSignUpComplete;

class AttachGuestOrderToUser
{
    /**
     * You guessed it: attach a guest order to a specific user.
     *
     * @param  UserQuickSignUpComplete  $event
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle(UserQuickSignUpComplete $event)
    {
        \Auth::user()->order()->attach(\Session::get('last_transaction.order_id'));
    }
}
```

In general, event listeners are a specific kind of service, so this should intuitively makes sense to future code readers.

Comment: Because the logic is in the listener handle, how would we test this in phpunit?

Comment: @Imran `new AttachGuestOrderToUser`, call `handle` with test data, and have `\Auth` mock its user call.